# Microsoft Graph invalid filter clause

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, microsoft-graph-api

I want to query users in my tenant by user type using msgraph with pagination. My initial request `await client.Users.Request()..` works but my code throws `ServiceException: Invalid filter clause` when I `await users.NextPageRequest`. Why do I not get this exception with my initial request if my filter clause is invalid? What is the correct way to query all users with pagination?

I am using .NET Framework 4.8 with Microsoft.Graph 4.1.0 and Microsoft.Graph.Core 2.0.1

Code:

```
public async Task<IList<GraphUser>> FindByUserType(string userType)
{
    IList<GraphUser> ret = new List<GraphUser>();
    if (Authenticate(out AuthToken token))
    {
        GraphServiceClient client = GetGraphServiceClient(token);
        string filter = $"UserType eq '{userType}'";
        IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await client.Users.Request()
            .Select(GraphProperties).Filter(filter).GetAsync();
        do
        {
            foreach (User user in users)
            {
                GraphUser graphUser = new GraphUser();
                MapGraphUser(graphUser, user);
                ret.Add(graphUser);
            }
            // Error happens when calling await users.NextPageRequest
        } while (users.NextPageRequest != null && (users = await users.NextPageRequest.GetAsync()).Count > 0);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

The `userType` parameter is specified using a constant:

```
public class GraphUserType
{
    public const string Member = "Member";
    public const string Guest = "Guest";
}
```

The client calls the service like so:

```
users.AddRange(await GraphService.FindByUserType(GraphUserType.Member));
users.AddRange(await GraphService.FindByUserType(GraphUserType.Guest));
```

Full exception:

```
Status Code: BadRequest Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException: Code: BadRequest Message: Invalid filter clause Inner error: AdditionalData: date: 2021-08-10T22:36:47 request-id: e36ee55f-5228-4df2-b218-4ea0fd155cd7 client-request-id: e36ee55f-5228-4df2-b218-4ea0fd155cd7 ClientRequestId: e36ee55f-5228-4df2-b218-4ea0fd155cd7
```

Comment: What kind value `userType` contains may I know? `userType` should be either `Member` or `Guest`

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I have added the constant and client code. `userType` is `Member` or `Guest`.

Comment: @Coffee You could try this way and let me know if that works for you, don't hasitate to ask for any further help.